# Material Button - Styles not being applied correctly, ugly as hell

Tags: android, material-design

**The ugly result:**

[image]

**My layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/material_text_button"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contact"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="59dp"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/material_button"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Default"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="114dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="109dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/material_text_button"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Colors:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorOnPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
    <color name="colorOnSurface">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorOnSurfaceSecondary">#d3d3d3</color>
    <color name="colorOnBackground">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

**Gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
//    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is it really meant to be so ugly by default? This is on API 21.

Material link: https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/

Comment: There's an error on your buttons. What is it?

Comment: You mean the red eclamation mark on the designer? That is because one of them is not constrained on both X and Y, doesn't affect the button's look though.

Comment: That's not the reason it's there. Just to confirm, I put a Button in a ConstraintLayout and don't even get a warning.

Comment: This is the default behavior though, you probably used "Infer Constraints" at some point or what not. Android Studio 3.1 clean install behaves like that. Really this has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: I've never had a warning or error with ConstraintLayouts, on any computer or any installation. Just for the sake of checking, check the red error (click the exclamation point in the top right of the design view).

Comment: I just constrained it and re-uploaded the layout pic, you can see the red exclamation is gone.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, when I run the app on the emulator, the buttons have a proper good look to them. Meaning, there is nothing wrong with what I am doing.

The Android Studio Preview seems to be in the wrong here, I can only wonder if that can be fixed.