# Material Button not properly showing on Preview

Tags: android, material-design

This question is related to my other question: [Material Button - Styles not being applied correctly, ugly as hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224903/material-button-styles-not-being-applied-correctly-ugly-as-hell)

Works fine when run on an emulator. API is 21, Android Studio v3.2.1. Is there a way to fix that?

**Preview:**

[image]

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/material_button"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="76dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="108dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Gradle:**

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
//    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.test.materialbuttontest01">

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I recommend you reference your previous question, otherwise people might start marking this as a duplicate of it. I certainly thought it was the same, having seen both, until I checked your (new) answer.

Comment: Done. Thought it was better to just post a new question instead of trying to get an answer for this on the other one.

Comment: It definitely is. You did the right thing. Your titles are just similar, as well as the content, so I suggested the linking.

Answer (score 18):

Choose another theme and it will work.[image]

Comment: Include the details from the picture in text

Answer (score 3):

Open your xml file(Ex: activity_main.xml) in **Design mode** and change theme to AppTheme or Any Other. In my case it worked with **AppTheme**.
[image]