# Showing different preview compare to device

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I just updated `compileSdkVersion` to 28 and using `com.android.support:design:28.0.0`
And I have a layout with couple of `TextInputEditText` and a `MaterialButton` my preview of android studio(version: 3.1.4) is different from real device(Samsung J5).

**`Layout Code:`**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    tools:context=".activity.LoginActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_movie_creation_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/emailId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:hint="Email-Id"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_work_black_24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ececec">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Category:"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp">
        </android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[Real Device Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw6hI.png)
 
[Android Studio Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxK6w.png)

Do I have to update my android studio? Please Help

Comment: Android Studio is currently at 3.2.1.  Not saying it will fix your problem but you should definitely update.

Comment: `android:layout_height="45dp"` don't hardcode your spinner height, use [qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support#qualifiers)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but this is just for test purpose I will do that later @LeoPelozo

Comment: Ok @JustinMorris

Comment: Seems someone else had the exact same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53229868/android-material-button-not-properly-showing-on-preview

Comment: Yes it's just pure luck he posted the same issue with difference of a minute @TheWanderer

Comment: Please ask about specific differences so we know exactly what your concern is.  The preview will never be identical to all devices.

Comment: The differences are clear sir `EditTexts` and `Buttons` are looking totally different.@JustinMorris